# How to use mame to run roms under the Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: mame

I want to play some rom games in the Ubuntu 17.04, I install mame and some roms, but do not know how to use the mame to run these roms,
anyone can help me ?
Tanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `mame` searches for ROMs in these directories:

```
$HOME/mame/roms
/usr/local/share/games/mame/roms
/usr/share/games/mame/roms
```

If you want to change that behaviour, edit the file `/etc/mame/mame.ini` with sudo rights and add your desired path to the `rompath` line, e. g. for your case:

```
rompath $HOME/mame/roms;/usr/local/share/games/mame/roms;/usr/share/games/mame/roms;$HOME/.mame/roms
```

This file is also the right choice to set other options permanently, e. g. `window 1` for window mode or `mouse 1` for mouse support.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the emulators for the software that you need it, install and download the [MAME ROMs](https://www.retrostic.com/roms/mame) and relax playing the games.